# How to supress mypy --no-untyped-def for parameters with default values?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Considering `example.py`:

```py
def my_func(a=1) -> int:
    return a * 10
```

Running `mypy --strict example.py` I get

```
example.py:1: error: Function is missing a type annotation for one or more arguments  [no-untyped-def]
example.py:2: error: Returning Any from function declared to return "int"  [no-any-return]
```

So I have to modify my function signature to include the type of the parameter `a` to be an `int`:

```py
def my_func(a: int = 1) -> int:
    return a * 10
```

This example is simple, but in some contexts, with more complex functions, this is a waste of time and is extremely verbose.

Is there a way to ignore, via mypy CLI or config file, `no-untyped-def` ***ONLY TO PARAMETERS THAT HAVE DEFAULT VALUES***?

Comment: No, there is no such way by design. If you omit the hint, it's `Any` - either with default or without it. Default's type is not inferred as parameter's type. You can have a look at [`basedmypy`](https://github.com/KotlinIsland/basedmypy) (no affiliation) if you want such inference and a few more awesome features, but beware: it's not PEP-compliant, less mature and supports some weird things like bare literals.